# Add scrollbar to table

Tags: html, css

I want to add a vertical and horizontal scroll bar to the table with fixed header.  By using `thead` and `tbody` tags I could add scrollbar in firefox but IE does not support the `overflow:auto property` in `tbody`. IE8 does not support css expressions so can you tell me how to accomplish this?

Comment: Overflow scroll should work

Answer (score 8):

with CSS it should be easy

```
div.scrollWrapper{

  height:250px;
  width:200px;
  overflow:scroll;
}


<div class="scrollWrapper">
<table >
<tbody height="xxx">
<tr>......

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

On giving fixed height also that is not working in IE. The height is getting applied to `tr` which I gave to `tbody`.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS for the task required:

```css
#tableID { overflow: scroll; }
```

HTML:

```
<table id="tableID">
...
</table>
```

About coloring visit this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/scrollbarColor.htm

Comment: the link you specified is no more longer valid. Please provide valid link.

Answer (score 0):

Try your original solution using `overflow:scroll`. You might also have to set a fixed height in `px` of the `tbody`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `overflow` set to `auto` the tbody will just show the overflow, you need to explicitly state `overflow: scroll` and have a fixed height for the `<tbody>`.

Comment: I cannot set fixed height to the tbody. Records may increase.

Comment: The fixed height determines how many records will be shown on screen and then the "overflow" will be shown with a scroll bar.